# iphone remove next string - leave rest of string after particular occurrence of string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring

In objective c how to Remove text after a string occurrence.

for example i have to remove a text after occurrence of text 'good'

'iphone is good but..' here i have to remove the but text in the end so the text will be now 'iphone is good'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
  NSArray *array = [string componentsSeperatedBy:@"good"];
  NSString *requiredString = [array objectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 4):

> Try with below code

```
NSString *str_good = @"iphone is good but...";
NSRange range = [str_good rangeOfString:@"good"];
str_good = [str_good substringToIndex:range.location+range.length];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
NSString * a = @"iphone is good but..";
NSRange match = [a rangeOfString:@"good"];
NSString * b = [a substringToIndex:match.location+match.length];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove rest of the string after a particular occurrence of "but", you can get the range of "but" and trim the original string down

```
NSString * test = [NSString stringWithString:@"iphone is good but rest of string"];
NSRange range = [test rangeOfString:@"but"];
if (range.length > 0)   {
    NSString *adjusted = [test substringToIndex:range.location];
    NSLog(@"result %@", adjusted);
}
```

EDIT
We can assume that the search does not want to cut of "butter is yellow", and can change the range to include " but"

```
NSRange range = [test rangeOfString:@" but"];
```

Comment: This will leave the space before "but" in the result string.

Comment: @JoshCaswell thanks, I was aware of that.  You raise a good point and made me think about the situation in my edit. "butter is yellow".

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *array = [string componentsSeparatedByString:stringToSearch];
NSString *requiredString;
if ([array count] > 0) {
    requiredString = [[array objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingString:stringToSearch];
}
```